# Supabase-js insert geometry objects

Tags: gis, supabase, supabase-database

I'm trying to insert geometry objects into my supabase postgres table.

I have the following geometry columns:

| Column name | Data type |
| --- | --- |
| point | POINT |
| line_string | LINESTRING |
| polygon | POLYGON |

I have tried multiple ways to insert POINT objects (I haven't gotten to the linestrings or polygons, seeing that they are more complicated).

```js
const geometry = { x: -123, y: -123 }

const point = `(${geometry.x}, ${geometry.y})`; // Try number 1
const point = `point(${geometry.x},${geometry.y})`; // Try number 2
const point = `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(${geometry.y}, ${geometry.x}), 4326)`; // Try number 3

const { data, error } = await supabase.from('geometries').upsert({ point });
```

All three gave the same error:

```
{
  message: 'parse error - invalid geometry',
  code: 'XX000',
  details: null,
  hint: '"(0" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry'
}
```

```
{
  message: 'parse error - invalid geometry',
  code: 'XX000',
  details: null,
  hint: '"point(0, 0" <-- parse error at position 10 within geometry'
}
```

```
{
  message: 'parse error - invalid geometry',
  code: 'XX000',
  details: null,
  hint: '"ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry'
}
```

How do I insert/upsert point objects? Linestrings? Polygons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `point`, you have to remove the comma between the coordinates values.

```js
POINT(${geometry.x} ${geometry.y})
```

Let me know how it goes with this!

Answer (score 1):

As written [here](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OpenGISWKBWKT):

> Well-Known Binary (WKB) provides a portable, full-precision representation of spatial data as binary data (arrays of bytes)

Concerning precision we can read [here](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsBinary.html):

> WKB format is useful to read geometry data from the database and maintaining full numeric precision. This avoids the precision rounding that can happen with text formats such as WKT.

Geometries can be transformed in `WKB` with OpenLayers. This way we don't need to use PostGIS functions in our query. Based on the [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_WKB-WKB.html) I managed to update/insert geometries as WKB.

```js
import WKB from 'ol/format/WKB';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';

const pointCoordinates = [...,...];

const feature = new Feature({
    geometry: new Point(pointCoordinates),
});

const format = new WKB();

const geomWKB = format.writeFeature(feature);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with well-known binary. Can you give more details on how this would help with a postgres insert statement?